# Sort array with two different conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve an exercise where I have to sort an array. I have to sort it in a particular way: from the biggest number to the smallest number, from the lowest numbers of numbers to the highest numbers of numbers.

Example: if the given array is

```
[1, 6, 12, 66, 66, 66, 44, 44, 44, 34, 34, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 122, 122, 122, 122]
```

the result should be:

```
[12, 6, 1, 34, 34, 66, 66, 66, 44, 44, 44, 4, 4, 4, 122, 122, 122, 122, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

My idea was to measure the length of the same elements in the array and sort them from lowest to highest, and then sort the biggest to the smallest number. I cannot even get past the point of comparing the elements with one another, let alone the length of them. Is it normal to be that difficult to compare elements with each other? This is just one of the hundreds of different attempts to compare.

```js
function sortIt(arr){
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = arr.length - 1; j <= 0; j--) {
      if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
 console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little more with proper examples? How 12 being the first number?

Comment: The sort criteria, according to your expected result, are stated backwards. The primary sort key appears to be the value frequency ("numbers of numbers").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to transform the array into an array of objects so you can keep the original values and the occurrence counts. Then you can sort that on both keys, strip out only the values afterwards:

```js
const array = [1, 6, 12, 66, 66, 66, 44, 44, 44, 34, 34, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 122, 122, 122, 122];

function sortIt(arr) {
  let oarr = array.reduce((accum, v) => (accum[v] = accum[v] ? accum[v]+1 : 1, accum), {});
  let combined = array.map(v => ({ value: v, count: oarr[v] }));
  return combined.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count || b.value - a.value).map(o => o.value);
}

console.log(sortIt(array));
```

In that code, first `oarr` is constructed to count the occurrences of each value. The second step creates a new array of objects with properties for the original value and the count. The last step performs the sort and then builds an array from only the values in the sorted result.

The sort comparison compares the value counts *first*, which is what your expected result requires. In general, when you have to sort on multiple "keys", the correct approach is to use a comparison function that works from the *most* important key to the *least* important key. Here, that's done by this function:

```
(a, b) => a.count - b.count || b.value - a.value
```

If the counts are the same, then `a.count - b.count` will return 0, so the `||` evaluation will proceed to the value comparison. If the counts, are different, however, then that's the result of the comparison because the values don't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will take some time now to study how you did it.  It kinda blows my mind just looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation, but there's tons of other things that I don't get in the solution. Like for example, everything. I'm a very beginner of js, still learning methods and trying to wrap my head around the logic of how to talk to a program. I have a general idea of what the reduce method does, but what comes after that arrow function, I cannot read. I cannot read what comes after either. I understand the idea on how you did it, but the code is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: Well if you're really just getting started, this exercise is probably too involved no matter how you might approach the problem. Sorting in itself is complicated. JavaScript has a fairly rich collection of tools (especially now in 2020) available for all sorts of common tasks, but for that reason it takes a long time to gain familiarity.